# android socket wait specified time for incoming data

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

In my recent app , I'm trying to Connect to a server through a Socket and send some Data to it , and wait specified time for server response.

after that Close the Connection. (`ServerConnect` is `MyAsyncTask`)

1 - for obvious reason I used `AsyncTask` which will run after I press a button.

```
public void btn_login_clicked(View v)
{
    if(ed1.getText().length()>0 && ed2.getText().length()>0)
    {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait...", "Waiting for Server...",true);
            ServerConnect conecction = new ServerConnect();
            conecction.execute();
    }else
    {
            Toast.makeText(this, "user and/or pass is wrong"+ed2.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In my `AsyncTask` I make a socket and initialize it for an IP and port.

After that I sent data to server , wait for 5 sec.

During this time if the server replayed I make an intent to transfer me to `MainActivity`. if not  want to

**1- close the socket**

**2- dismiss the progressDialog**

**3- let user to push the button again.**

**Code:**

```
public class ServerConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    /*my global parameter*/
    public ServerConnect()
    {
        /*do some initialization */
    }
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    String Packet = null;

    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port); //connect to server
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        Thread.sleep(200);
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
        Packet = Preamble + Username + "\n" + Pass; 
        Thread.sleep(200);
        out.println(Packet); // send data
        long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true)
        {
            br.read(myData);
            ReceivedText = new String(myData);
            Thread.sleep(10);
            if(ReceivedText.length() > 0)
                break;
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timeNow >= 5000) // for getting rid of Progress dialig and let user try again
            {
                progress.dismiss();
                socket.close();
                socket = null;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(ReceivedText.toCharArray()[0] == 'T')// if ok go to main activity
        {
            ReceivedText = "";
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginPage.this, MainActivity.class);
            LoginPage.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        if(ReceivedText.toCharArray()[0] == 'X') // if not do nothing yet
        {
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

The problem is even when I sleep the server to reply after 20 sec `myAsyncTask` waits and never dismiss the `progressDialog` after 5 sec and get the data and goes to `MainActivity`.

**is my implementation wrong ??**

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should be calling dismiss eight er onpostExecute or using runOnUiThread method

Answer (score 0):

> is my implementation wrong ??

Yup.

Get rid of all the sleeps and `System.currentTimeMillis()` calls, and call `Socket.setSoTimeout()` with the desired read timeout in milliseconds. If the timeout expires during a `read()` call it will throw `SocketTimeoutException`, which you should therefore catch.

```
br.read(myData);
```

It is impossible to write correct networking code without storing the result returned by `read()` into a variable. You have to check it for -1, indicating end of stream, or a positive value, indicating how many bytes were actually read.